# Remove duplicate element in a string

Tags: c++, string, recursion, character

Given a string of characters, we need to remove all the duplicate characters in the given string.

This is tutorial file given by my professor.

This is working properly except for the test cases like:

Test case:

```
Expected output:

{a,b,a,c,d} --> {a,b,c,d}

Output Received:

{a,b,a,c,d} --> {a,b,a,c,d}
```

My code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;



string removeDup(string s){
   if(s.length()==0){
       return "";
   }

   char ch = s[0];
   string ans = removeDup(s.substr(1));

   if(ch==ans[0]){
       return ans;
   }

   return (ch+ans);
}   

int main(){

   cout<<removeDup("abacd")<<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Please send the solution using recursion,if possible.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this. One is to sort the list, then duplicate elements are going to be consecutive, so finding them will be easy.

Comment: Obligatory links to [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) Using both together can get really bad. Sounds like you're not facing a bug yet, but when you have a mystery error in your code, removing these two lines should be among the first things you try. Preferably avoid all of the problems caused by them by not using them in the first place

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicates-from-a-given-string/

Comment: I recommend Ignoring the above link. It's the kind of example that makes you a worse C++ programmer rather than better.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to remove duplicate elements in non-sorted array is managing a set of elements already seen and add the element to the result only if it is not seen before.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

void removeDupInternal(const string& data, size_t pos, string& out, std::set<char>& used){
    if (pos < data.size()){
         if (used.find(data[pos]) == used.end()){
             out += data[pos];
             used.insert(data[pos]);
         }
         removeDupInternal(data, pos + 1, out, used);
    }
}

string removeDup(string s){
    string result;
    std::set<char> used;
    removeDupInternal(s, 0, result, used);
    return result;
}

int main(){

   cout<<removeDup("abacd")<<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can be simply done by:

```
    string input="abagkfcd";

    string output= "";
    for(char& ch: input)
        if(output.find(ch) == string::npos)
            output +=  ch;

    cout<<output;
```

> Using Recursion; may not be my best but here is the try

```
string removeDup(string ip, string& op){

    if(not ip.empty())
    {
        if(op.find(ip[0]) == string::npos)
            op += ip[0];
        removeDup(std::string(ip.begin()+1, ip.end()), op);
    }
    return op;

}

int main(){

    string input="abagkggffkfcd";
    string output{};

    removeDup(input, output);

    cout<<output;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the effort,but I need my solution using recursion.

Comment: @pekking add recursive approach, its very easy to understand, let me know if you need further clarification

Comment: hey can you please explain your second if condition.

Comment: we will add any incoming `char` in the output string only if it does not exist in the current output string. this way we will avoid duplicates in output string

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/